# Why TPanel does not show correct frame/border in Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Tpanel does not show the top and left border under Delphi XE/Win 7.
Why?

Example (I just dropped few TPanel from pallete to my form, inside of a TTabSheet):

[image]

How do I make it look like the original Delphi 7 control (with all 4 borders), without changeing its properties every time I place it on my form?

Comment: do you have a screenshot to illustrate?

Comment: OK, so your *actual* question is *how do I change the background colour of the panel?*

Comment: (There *is* a white top-left border in your pictures above. But since the panel background is also white, it is somewhat difficult to see it.)

Comment: (Or are you actually thinking about the `TGroupBox`, and not the `TPanel`?)

Comment: Your screenshots actually are panels inside tabsheets, is that right?

Comment: @David - Yes, it is an a TTabSheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `ParentBackground` to `false`.

[image: A blue panel on a green form]

Above is a blue panel on a green form (`ParentBackground = false`). Notice the white upper-left border and the gray bottom-right border. Of course, if both the form and the panel are white, the white border will become invisible.

Comment: By the way, the caption of the form is U+222B INTEGRAL SIGN, one of my favourite Unicode characters.

Comment: The screenshots that OP presents are from a `TPanel` inside a `TTabSheet` unless I am very much mistaken.

Comment: @David: It could also be a `TPanel` on a white `TForm`. If the OP is putting his panels on a tab sheet, he should say so!

Answer (score 2):

That is how it meant to be drawn. The 3D effect is as if there was a light source shining from the top left. That's why the bottom and right edges are in a shadow cast by the raised panel.

---

Regarding your updated question, it sounds like you want your application to run without themes. The easiest way is to uncheck "Enable runtime themes" in the Application pane of the project settings.

But of course that would look odd nowadays. If you are using the panel to group related controls, perhaps a group box would be better. My instincts are that panels with raised borders will look poor on modern themed Windows.

Comment: +1 for giving an answer that any of us would have been able to!

Comment: I just want to have the old/classic Tpanel, that I had in Delphi 7/Win XP. The 3D effect was much better than the current one. And the panel was more contained.

Comment: @thelight: The `TPanel` uses a bevel that is inconsistent with the appearance of modern versions of Windows. `TPanel` was designed back in the Windows 3.1/9x era.